# SpecRun / VSTest - What is internal structure of directory paths

Tags: vstest.console.exe, specrun

I'm new to implementing SpecRun/SpecFlow. I'm really struggling with runsettings, profiles, and the directory paths. The end result of all this is to be running our webtests in an Azure environment, hopefully posting results into TFS. But I cannot understand why SpecRun does what it is doing. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to word this.

The documentation states that all files are relative to the baseFolder. It states the that the baseFolder should be the bin folder (bin\debug, in my case.) All output will be relative to that folder. That's my first source of stress. Personally, I don't want anything altering the bin folder. All that kind  report/logs stuff should be written elsewhere, no where near the bin folder.

My application is sensitive to *its* base folder, the *current* folder of the project. It is understood that current folder is where the processing is kicked off from (cd \project\process; exec process.) It is that folder where the application picks up its environment settings. But processing bombs with the following error:

`Could not find a part of the path 'C:\classes\defaulttestdata\default_data_values.json'`

What changed the current directory from the project to c:\ ? Why is it doing that. I'm finding myself having to redesign how parameters are being passed in, and what assumptions I can make internally in the application.

It gets more complex when testing is started with vstest.console using a .runsetting, which inturn references a profile.  specifes the name .srprofile, which is located in the project folder. However, processing bombs because it cannot find it:

`> vstest.console bin\debug\rti.accidents.web.webtesting.dll --Settings:console.runsettings`

`Could not find file 'C:\Code\Branches\NIEDO2\V4\Accidents\RTI.Accidents.Web.WebTesting\bin\debug\specrun.srprofile'`

How did it know where to get the bin\debug folder from to go look there? Profile says specrun.srprofile, not bin\debug\specrun.profile?

I have no clue where output and logs is going. After all my attempts, I have found c:\TestResults, c:\TestResults, and c:\bin\debug\TestResults. Sometimes there is output; sometimes not.

Everything behaves real nice inside of Visual Studio. It runs everything hunky dory, puts the output where I want it relative to the project (not the bin).

Is there someone out there that has been successful in using vstest.console that would be willing to share copy of their .runsettings and .srprofile so I can get a visual of how it all comes together. Has anyone else raise the argument "you don't write back to an applications bin folder." In some cases, that protected space and you don't want reports/logs pigging up a c:\ drive.

Sorry, just a little frustrated with feeling like an idiot.

Comment: Hi, maintainer of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+ here. In this case it would be easier, if you open an issue on GitHub https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow for your behaviour. I need some information to give an answer that is missing here. There we have an issue template that asks for all of this needed information.

Comment: @AndreasWillich - Thanks for the response. I went out to your site and began crafting an explanation of my issues. The more I wrote, the more I thought, and that resulted in me wising up and resolving my own issues. I need to rethink things, less from Ruby perspective and more in a .net perspective. Thank you.